# How to extract types from tuple type?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a code

```scala
case class MyTypeTag[T] () 

def getTypeTags[TT <: Product : TypeTag] = {
  val subtypesTags: List[MyTypeTag[Option[_]] = ???  
  sybtypesTags
}

val res = getTypeTags[(Int, String, Boolean)] 
// res = MyTypeTag[Option[Int]] :: MyTypeTag[Option[String]] :: MyTypeTag[Option[Boolean]] :: Nil
```

so i want to call function `getTypeTags` passing any tuple type as type parameter and get list of `MyTypeTag` instances with each type inside tuple wrapped in `Option`

if in intelliJ i evaluate expression `typeof[TT]` i see property `args` with list of my types, but i do not know how to access from code. Or may be some other ways can be apllied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the signature of `getTypeTags`? Do you want it to return `List[MyTypeTag[Option[_]]`? Then this contradicts `res = MyTypeTag[Option[Int]] :: ...  :: Nil`. All elements of a list have the same type. Do you want an `HList` instead of `List`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin, but it depends on what tuple-type parameter i passed, so there is just example, return type is List[MyTypeTag[Option[_]], where placeholder can be whatsoever

Comment: List is okay, now i don't want to go into shapless staff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type parameter `T` in `case class MyTypeTag[T]()` must be known at compile time. But it seems you try to define it using runtime reflection. This can't work (unless you define the class at runtime: `toolbox.define(q"case class MyTypeTag[T]()")` but this would be tricky).

You can try to use compile-time reflection

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def getTypeTags[TT <: Product]: List[MyTypeTag[_ <: Option[_]]] = 
  macro getTypeTagsImpl[TT]

def getTypeTagsImpl[TT: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  weakTypeOf[TT].typeArgs.map(t => q"MyTypeTag[Option[$t]]()")
    .foldRight[Tree](q"Nil")((t, ts) => q"$t :: $ts")
}
```

Usage:

```
getTypeTags[(Int, String, Boolean)] //List(MyTypeTag(), MyTypeTag(), MyTypeTag())
```

In order to verify that the code works properly let's temporarily modify `MyTypeTag`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

case class MyTypeTag[T]()(implicit val typeTag: TypeTag[T])

val res = getTypeTags[(Int, String, Boolean)]
res(0).typeTag // TypeTag[Option[Int]]
res(1).typeTag // TypeTag[Option[String]]
res(2).typeTag // TypeTag[Option[Boolean]]
```

You can also use Shapeless instead of macros

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{FillWith, Mapped, ToList}
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, Poly0}

case class MyTypeTag[T]()

def getTypeTags[TT <: Product] = new {
  def apply[L <: HList, L1 <: HList]()(implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[TT, L],
    mapped: Mapped.Aux[L, λ[X => MyTypeTag[Option[X]]], L1],
    fillWith: FillWith[myTypeTagPoly.type, L1],
    toList: ToList[L1, MyTypeTag[_ <: Option[_]]]
  ): List[MyTypeTag[_ <: Option[_]]] = 
    fillWith().toList
}

object myTypeTagPoly extends Poly0 {
  implicit def cse[A]: Case0[MyTypeTag[Option[A]]] = at(MyTypeTag[Option[A]]())
}

getTypeTags[(Int, String, Boolean)]() // List(MyTypeTag(), MyTypeTag(), MyTypeTag())
```

If you make `MyTypeTag` covariant (`MyTypeTag[+T]`) then `List[MyTypeTag[_ <: Option[_]]]` can be replaced with `List[MyTypeTag[Option[_]]]`.

Comment: Thanks! Tomorrow with fresh look i will analize how it works. Just one thing - `case class MyTypeTag[T]()(implicit val typeTag: TypeTag[T])` - in my real class i'm actually using this, so the question is: can i be sure that if i print typeTag and get proper name as Option[Int] it is gurantee that it works properly, and if i get strings like $7 $8 it means that it does not really work even if no exceptions were threw

Comment: @DmitryReutov It's hard to say without understanding what "works properly" means. You didn't provide details how you're going to use your `MyTypeTag` machinery. Surely it's better not to rely on raw strings.

Comment: in simple words i create a type for doobie query - some orm system. For example i  pass MyTypeTag to function `def query[T, T1, T2](statement, model: T, type1: MyTypeTag[T1], type2: MyTypeTag[T2]) = statement.query[T, (T1, T2)].to[List]`. In some magic way it works inspite T, T1, T2 are not directly known at compile time and creating dinamicly according some conditions in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't distinguish between an instance of `MyTypeTag[Int]` and an instance of `MyTypeTag[String]` at runtime (to check this for yourself, try

```
val l = List(MyTypeTag[Option[Int]](), MyTypeTag[Option[String]](), MyTypeTag[Option[Boolean]]())
```

and see what that gives you, and what you can and can't do with it), so the answer to the question as you ask it is

```
def getTypeTags[TT <: Product](implicit tt: TypeTag[TT]): List[MyTypeTag[_]] = {
  tt.tpe.typeParams.map(_ => MyTypeTag[Option[_]]())
}
```

You can get the type parameters with `tt.tpe.typeParams`, but since that's a runtime value, you can't recover that as a compile-time type `T` for `MyTypeTag[T]` since it doesn't exist at compile-time yet.

Maybe you can leverage shapeless to do whatever it is you want to do, it has ways to abstract over tuples. See https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/

Comment: *"You can't distinguish between an instance of `MyTypeTag[Int]` and an instance of `MyTypeTag[String]` at runtime..."* Well, type tags are exactly to overcome type erasure.

Comment: Also you confused `typeArgs` with `typeParams`.

Comment: In scala-scastie it works perfectly well, but in intelliJ i get an error `unbound wildcard type
    tt.tpe.typeArgs.map(_ => MyTypeTag[_]())`. What is it about?

Comment: And could you please provide simple example how to extract types from shapeless Generic, i read half of documentation but didn't see such example

Comment: This way it works, but i can not check now if v.type contains right type `tt.tpe match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args.map(v => MyTypeTag[Option[v.type]]) }`

Comment: @DmitryReutov `v.type` is a singleton type. This not gonna work.

Comment: You'd need a `TypeTag[MyTypeTag[T]]` then, which seems to somewhat defeat the point.

Comment: @Martijn I guess `TypeTag[T]` can be enough.